# GWAN not recognising Sun Java 7

Tags: java, sun, g-wan

**OS:**
Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop

**Java installed:**
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

Running sudo ./gwan gives following error:-
Please install OpenJDK or SUN Java
.

> 'report.java': to use Java (*.java) scripts, install 'javac' (sudo apt-get install javac).
>
> 'loan.java': to use Java (*.java) scripts, install 'javac' (sudo apt-get install javac).
>
> 'argv.java': to use Java (*.java) scripts, install 'javac' (sudo apt-get install javac)..
>
> 'hello.mm': to use Objective-C++ (*.mm) scripts, install 'gobjc++' (sudo apt-get install gobjc++)
>
> 'all.java': to use Java (*.java) scripts, install 'javac' (sudo apt-get install javac)

Javac, Java both in sys path, both available in terminal

I have not touched any configuration files just went through
http://gwan.com/download
then
tried heading over to

localhost:8080/?hello.java

note: all C files work.

Have not tried openJDK though I would like to stay away from this option.

Comment: Is OpendJDK exists in your system?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to tell which JVM should be used. The G-WAN site has a dedicated Java [FAQs entry](http://gwan.com/faq#languages) for that question.

Reporting the same kind of problems in the past I have been told that the next release will be more JVM-agnostic.

Comment: aaah okay.. I'll try setting that. Currently I just have $PATH.

Comment: no luck\\


krone@ubuntu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle


krone@ubuntu:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin


Same error as before. Does Gwan support Sun Java 7?